# Adding nodes to Cloudera Quickstart VM

Tags: cloudera, cloudera-manager, cloudera-quickstart-vm

I have Cloudera Quickstart VM installed and it is single node. How can I add multi nodes to it and make it as a cluster ? I am now using Virtualboax and tried to clone the base quickstart VM and then network it and use the Add Cluster wizard in Cloudera manager. But it is failing. Anyone knows how to add multiple nodes to it ?

Answer (score 1):

Your quickest/easiest option (instead of using a VM) is to install the multi-node version of QuickStart for Docker:

http://blog.cloudera.com/blog/2016/08/multi-node-clusters-with-cloudera-quickstart-for-docker/

Or, you could use Vagrant to set up a virtualized multi-node cluster:

http://blog.cloudera.com/blog/2014/06/how-to-install-a-virtual-apache-hadoop-cluster-with-vagrant-and-cloudera-manager/